# OpenCV Image shift

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I just want to shift my image left or right. Meaning I have an image with 640x480 and i want to shift it 120 to the left.

`void AnaglyphUtils::adjustBaseline(const Mat &img, Mat &shifted_img)` my method:

```
int shift = 120 // meaning, shift of 120

rect1 = cv::Rect(0,0, img.cols-shift, img.rows);
rect_shifted = cv::Rect(shift,0, img.cols-shift, img.rows);
Rect rect1, rect_shifted;

rect1 = cv::Rect(shift,0, img.cols-shift, img.rows);
rect_shifted = cv::Rect(0,0, img.cols-shift, img.rows);

tmp = shifted_img1(rect_shifted);
img(rect1).copyTo(tmp);

// out image shifted_img
```

This results to the an image which is 640-120x480. And know I'm trying to make a new image 
with the original size 640x480 combined with the tmp image. It should start with the image up to 640-120 and the rest should be just black. I already found the `adjustROI` function but I'm not sure how to use it. thx for any help.

Comment: I already read this post. It'S not working...

Comment: its not doing the thing, whats he'd asked I want an image back which hast the same size as the original and thats not what the answer is about. I already tried it. and i think my question is simple. I have an smaller image and i want to put it an a black image with the original size.

Comment: the other question does that. it initializes a black matrix (full size) and copies a smaller matrix to a sub-part of the full black matrix.

Comment: as you can see if have basiclly the same code. but my image is resized to a image which has the size of the part I want to copy/move.

Comment: For better understanding, just attach input and output(approx) image you need, for both cases: left shift and right shift.